# vscode の explorer でファイルの横に表示されるビックリマークは何を表す？

Tags: vscode

vscode でプロジェクトを開いていると、 explorer のファイルの左に、ビックリマークが表示されることがあることに気づきました。

[image: ビックリマーク付きファイルエントリー]

#### 質問

- これは、何を表しますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Seti UIのTheme](https://github.com/jesseweed/seti-ui/)で、[YAMLのアイコンが「！」で定義](https://github.com/jesseweed/seti-ui/blob/master/icons/yml.svg)されています。

お使いのテーマが一致する場合、.ymlの拡張子のファイルであることを表現していると思われます。